# Create an instance of object from Blender asset browser using scripting

Tags: python, scripting, asset-browser, asset

[image]

How to create an instance of a particular object from the asset browser library using the python scripting.

Comment: Hello ! So you want to instantiate an asset in the current scene using the asset browser parameters ? How does the script choose which asset to create if there are more than one ?

Comment: Yes, I want to instantiate one object at a time using its name from Asset Browser.

Comment: Several assets can share the same name in the asset browser. Should it choose the first one it finds ?

Comment: Yes it will be okay if it finds the first one.